# capture FTP traffic for both active and passive FTP sessions

Tags: networking, tcpdump

I understand that the command `tcpdump` can be used to capture traffic.  How would I use that to record all the active and passive FTP traffic on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Read `man tcpdump`. Find the `port` to monitor with `grep ftp /etc/services`.